# how can I delete my openid account?

Tags: support, openid

I have a duplicate openid account which I'd like to delete. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [your account page.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/202311/barnabas-szabolcs)  Click on **My Logins** in the upper right hand corner.  Click the X circle of the login you want to remove.

Comment: This doesn't delete his _OpenID_ account

Comment: Any idea how can i delete the OpenID itself?